# Data not being formatted as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I am doing the following in a Facebook Request:

```
function sendRequests() {
                FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests',
                message: "You are invited to the surprise Birthday",
                data:{"board_id":<%=@board.id%>}
```

When I get the request object from the user who accepted the application I parse it as a JSON object as follows:

ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request_body.body)

All of the information is formatted as a Hash should in Rails except for the data I sent in which looks as follows:

```
"data"=>"{\"board_id\":1}"
```

I have tried all kinds of combinations but it just won't convert properly. Am I missing something or does the JSON returned by the facebook graph api need to be formatted differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did the following:

In the facebook fb.ui

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
    exclude_ids: <%=@invited_guests.map{|guest| guest.provider_user_id} %>,
        message: <%="'You are invited to the surprise Birthday board for #{@board.bp_name}'" %>,
             title: "Come celebrate with us",
    data: "board_id:<%=@board.id%>"
```

Then in the controller after the request is accepted in facebook:

```
request_content = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request_body.body)
      board = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request_content["data"])
```

I have to decode twice. Once for the whole request and the second time for the specific data information passed. It might not be pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the data and validating it manually here: http://jsonlint.com/

It has helped me numerous times.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I tried it but it still comes back in that strange format.